# How to call a function a certain time after last change in TextView?

Tags: java, android, timer, textview, countdowntimer

I want to call a function only once if there hasn't been any change in textView for a certain time (say 25 seconds). I don't want this function to be called after it has been called once regardless of any changes to the TextView after its initial call.

I was trying to achieve this goal by using timers and TextChangedListener. This is the code I have so far:

```
textResult.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
     //check to cancel timer when there is a new change
     shouldTimerReset = true;
 }

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

     CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(24000, 100) {
         @Override
         public void onTick(long l) {
             if (shouldTimerReset ){
                 cancel();
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
             //call functions
             writeToFileExt(textResult.getText().toString());
             setButtonLabel(R.id.buttonReadAudio, "Read Audio");
             addItemsOnSpinnerModels();
             cancel();
             //Log.i ("Timer:", "Second timer");

         }
     }.start();

 }
});
```

My idea was that a new timer would be instantiated after every change but because of a check it will be cancelled onTextChanged during the next change, so one timer at the end will stay active which will call the function onFinish.

However, the function is getting called several times and I don't know where I am going wrong. Is there a fault in the logic or in the code? How do I fix this? Any other suggestion to achieve the end goal would also be appreciated. I do not necessarily need to use timers. What would be the best method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Handler outside of the listener.

```
import android.os.Handler;

private final Handler handler;


...
handler = new Handler();
...
@Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        void run(){
             writeToFileExt(textResult.getText().toString());
             setButtonLabel(R.id.buttonReadAudio, "Read Audio");
             addItemsOnSpinnerModels();
             cancel();
      }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,25000);
 }
...
```

You don't need to call annything onTextChange because right afterwards the method afterTextChanged is called. Method handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) will cancel all the pending runnables in the que. After the text change, new runnable will be set to run in 25 seconds. If afterTextChange will not be called in 25 seconds, stuff that is in run() method will be executed.

Comment: Thank you. This worked except I just had to add another check in the run method to make sure that the functions are called only once and not every time there is a delay of more than 25s in TextView change.